# How can i select and move edge loop created by subdivision modifier before hitting apply button?

Tags: modeling

How can i select and move edge loops created by subdivision modifier before hitting apply button ?

Comment: The short answer is you cannot.

Comment: the bit longer answer is: you can - with geometry nodes ;)